# ERROR TypeError: _co.deleteConsulta is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

i was following a tutorial how to make a crud using firestore, and thus far i got everything working right until i got the part that i had to delete the  data from firestore, everytime i click it to delete an user from my firestore i get the error saying that ._co.deleteConsulta is not a function, even though it was declared inside my detailpage.ts, and it shows no error, i even tried to run ionic serve --prod to see if i was missing anything, no errors whatsoever.

For the second part whenever i click delete, nothing happens 
no errors are shown at all.

here's my detail.ts

```
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FirestoreService } from './../../services/data/firestore.service';
import { Consulta } from './../../model/consulta.interface';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.page.scss'],
})
export class DetailPage implements OnInit {
  public consulta: Observable<Consulta>;
  public consultaId;
  constructor(private firestoreService: FirestoreService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute, private alertController: AlertController, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const consultaId: string = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.consulta = this.firestoreService.getConsultaDetail(consultaId).valueChanges();
  }
  async deletarConsulta() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      message: 'Tem certeza que gostaria de desmarcar sua consulta?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: blah => {
            console.log('Confirm desmarcação: blah');
          },
        },
        {
          text: 'Okay',
          handler: () => {
            this.firestoreService.deleteConsulta(this.consultaId).then(() => {
              this.router.navigateByUrl('');
            });
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    await alert.present();
  }

}
```

detail.html

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title>{{ (consulta | async)?.unidade }}</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content padding>
      <h3> Unidade </h3>
      <p>
        Médico{{ (consulta | async)?.medNome }}
      </p>
      <p> Especialidade{{ (consulta | async)?.especialidade }}</p>
      <p> Endereço{{ (consulta | async)?.endereco }}</p>
      <p> Data da Consulta {{ (consulta | async)?.data }}</p>
      <p> Hora da Consulta {{ (consulta | async)?.hora }}</p>
      <ion-button expand="block" (click)="deletarConsulta()">
          Desmarcar Consulta
        </ion-button>
    </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't wrote the function `deleteConsulta()` or it is missing on the `firestoreService` file code. And also, you could maybe try to change the access from 'private' to 'public' in the Constructor declarations...